# Reload ListView with ObservableCollection

Tags: listview, xamarin, observablecollection

Hi I have a problem with a `ListView`. The problem is that when I change add new element to the Colletion, the view will not refresh.

I have created two button left and right button that I use to change date. The function will make an http call and the response is a list of item. Each item of the list is put into the collection that is associated to the `ListView`

The `ListView` is created in this way

```
var exercisesPlan = new ListView ();

exercisesPlan.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (() => {
    ViewCell cell = new ViewCell ();

    //template here
    return cell;
});

exercisesPlan.SetBinding (ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding ("ExercisesWorkoutPlan", BindingMode.TwoWay));
exercisesPlan.SetBinding (ListView.SelectedItemProperty, new Binding ("DailyWorkoutPlan", BindingMode.TwoWay));
exercisesPlan.RowHeight = 65;
```

The function associated to the two buttons is

```
//Start spinner
try
{
    DateTime dtNew = fdvm.CurrentDate.AddDays(1);

    if ((dtNew.Date - DateTime.Now.Date).Days <= 7)
    {
        await fdvm.UpdateAll(dtNew);

    }
}
//Catch Here
```

Inside the UpdateAll I do

```
ExercisesWorkoutPlan.Clear();
foreach(PlanWorkoutProfile wpPlan in wpPlans){
    var response = //Make http call

    DailyWorkout dpw = new DailyWorkout();
    dpw.PlanId = wpPlan.PlanId;
    dpw.WorkoutName = response.Result.WorkoutName;
    dpw.Exercises = response.Result.Exercises;

    ExercisesWorkoutPlan.Add(dpw);
}
```

If I set a breakpoint at the end of the `UpdateAll` function the `Collection` ExercisesWorkoutPlan seams to be ok but the view will be empty. It seams that the `Clear` method works but the `Add` no

**What I have tried**

1) I have tried to comment the line where i clear the collection, and I see that the view will update with the elements of the previuos date when I change date by clicking on the left or right button

2) I have tried to set null  ItemsSource property and then assign the Collection again after `await fdvm.UpdateAll(dtNew);`

3) I have tried to assing the fdvm.ExercisesWorkoutPlan directly to ItemsSource but still not working

Comment: instead of binding ItemsSourceProperty, try just setting ItemsSource = ExercisesWorkoutPlan

Comment: I have already tried but It not works